# How to copy/paste files from Linux to Windows on Dual Boot locally?

Tags: dual-boot

I am trying to copy and paste a file from Linux to Windows using Dolphin File manager, however the option is greyed out. Is this not possible? or do I need to use something else?

I can see my windows files from Linux and copy them over to Linux, but i can't do the converse of copying Linux files to Windows just through using the file manager.

Note: My windows and Linux are both in the same hard disk: sda

Comment: Since you're able to read it, you should also be able to write to it. Was the Windows filesystem mounted as read-only?

Comment: I am not sure, how do i check if it was mounted as read-only?

So far the only workaround I was able to successfully do is use third party programs while being in Windows (Linux Reader for example). I avoided the use of Ext2fsd - it can cause a ton of problems like data corruption and bsods.

But i want to try if it is possible to copy and paste files from Linux to Windows just through using file managers. My hunch is it can't because of the different file system that my Linux is in: (Ext4)

Comment: The fact that you are able to read the files indicates that you already have the necessary filesystem drivers in place. If you didn't, the system would be unable to mount the device at all. To check if the filesystem is read-only, the easiest way is to use the mount command. Simply open up a terminal and run `mount`. It will print out the list of all mounts on your system, one per line. Then, find the line corresponding to the Windows filesystem. If an `ro` parameter is present on that line, the mount is read-only. Writable mounts will have an `rw` instead.

Comment: Linux NTFS driver will not mount NTFS if hibernated. And Windows fast startup sets hibernation flag. Updates also turn it back on, so you may have to regularly turn it off.http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation & https://superuser.com/questions/1231582/hdd-with-windows-boot-locked-because-of-hibernation-flag

Comment: Ok i have found the windows partition. It is /dev/sda6 and has a value of ro. How can i change it to rw? Are there any consequences or potential side effects from changing its read-write access from ro to rw?